# How to run multiple terminal in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using Xcode to do c++ programming and I have a c++ code, with different input arguments. I want to achieve that in Xcode, I could run multiple simultaneous running of my c++ code. However, the current problem is that once one code finishes, its terminal window automatically closed and I do not have time to look at its result. Thus computer time is wasted.

Is there a way to run multiple same c++ code with different arguments input? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way I try out is to copy the whole folder, open the new project in the new folder, run, and afterwards delete the folders when you don't need the multiple run anymore....